# Launching Android Browser in Full Screen Mode from App

Tags: java, android, browser, android-intent, fullscreen

Is there a way to launch the android browser from an app in Full Screen Mode such that the address bar is not visible? Any examples or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, a `WebView`  might be sufficient. Tutorial can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).

Comment: I've considered a webview but the app I'm working on is just a background service that allows a user to send commands to a device from a browser. I didnt want to bog down the app with UI besides the settings page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set full screen mode by

**First approach:**

just add to your `Manifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

**Second approach:**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

**Third approach:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```